# Algebraic spaces in the étale topology (proof from Stacks project)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes, algebraic-stacks, algebraic-spaces

I have a question about the proof of Lemma 78.12.1 from [Stacks Project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/076L). The aim of the last paragraph of the proof is to verify that the map of sheaves in the étale topology $F \to U/R$ is an isomorphism. By [Lemma 7.11.2](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00WN) our job is to show that it's surjective and injective. The proof that $F \to U/R$ is *injective* I not understand. The used argument is:

> On the other hand, the map $F \to U/R$ is injective (as a map of presheaves) since $R=U \times_{U/R} U$ again by Spaces, Theorem 63.10.5.

Why $R=U \times_{U/R} U$ imply that the map is injective?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall from the beginning of the [proof of the lemma](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/076L) that $R$ is defined to be $U \times_F U$, so the surjections $U \to F \to U/R$ induce a canonical étale sheaf map $U \times_{U/R} U \to U \times_F U$ that was shown to be an isomorphism.

Let's see what this means for a test object $S$.  Let $A = U(S)$, $B = F(S)$, $C = (U/R)(S)$, and let $f: A \to B$ and $g: B \to C$ be induced by the maps $U \to F \to U/R$ given before.  Then we are basically saying that, if we replace $S$ with a suitably fine étale cover, then the induced set map $A \times_C A \to A \times_B A$ is an isomorphism.  Here, $A \times_C A = \{ (x,y) \in A \times A | gf(x) = gf(y) \}$ and $A \times_B A = \{ (x,y) \in A \times A | f(x) = f(y) \}$.  That is to say, $gf(x) = gf(y)$ if and only if $f(x) = f(y)$, or $g$ is injective on the image of $f$.

Because $U \to F$ is a surjection of sheaves, we may assume $f$ is surjective after passing to a suitable cover.  We conclude that $g$ is injective, and hence $F \to U/R$ is injective.

Comment: everything is clear now except one step: Why is the induced $U \times_{U/R} U \to U \times_F U$ is an isomorphism?

Comment: @katalaveino That is the "used argument" you quoted, i.e., https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02WW

Comment: yes, I think I understand. Theorem 63.10.5 implies that since $R := U \times_F U \to U \times_S U$ is etale equiv relation, the data $(U,R, U \to U/R)$ is representation of $U/R$. But beeing represented by this data implies for $U/R$ *tautologically* that $R=U \times_{U/R} U$ holds? that's the point, right?